# Turn off backlight of the buttons

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android application that might be used at night. Therefor, I need to turn off the  buttons' backlight. How can I do this? On my own phone the backlight turns off after a while, but on the Motorola Droid I don't think this happens.

I'm using a wakelock to keep the screen on. Should I use another flag or how can I do this?

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, WAKE_LOCK_TAG);
mWakeLock.acquire();
```

Thank you very much!

//Kaloer

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?
im also looking to turn off back lights on the buttons.

Comment: Yes I did, or it was a new feature in Android 2.2. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892160/uimodemanager-nightmode-froyo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no API to control the backlight of the buttons -- sorry!

Comment: @pengwang, could you please at list paste a link to this API?

Answer (score 4):

There is a hack:

```
private void setDimButtons(boolean dimButtons) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    LayoutParams layoutParams = window.getAttributes();
    float val = dimButtons ? 0 : -1;
    try {
        Field buttonBrightness = layoutParams.getClass().getField(
                "buttonBrightness");
        buttonBrightness.set(layoutParams, val);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    window.setAttributes(layoutParams);
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I would call this a "hack". It's reflection.

Comment: that's interesting. Is there a way to access `getWindow()` from outside an activity, like in a service?

Answer (score 1):

I see that this is an old question that was mostly answered in a comment link, but to make it clear to anyone else who comes across this question, here's my own answer.

It's built-in since API 8. ([doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#buttonBrightness))

```
float android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.buttonBrightness
```

This is a somewhat modified/simplified version of what I'm using in one of my apps (excluding irrelevant code). The inner class is required to prevent a crash at launch on older platforms that don't support it.

```
private void nightMode() {
    Window win = getWindow();
    LayoutParams lp = win.getAttributes();
    if (prefs.getBoolean("Night", false))
        changeBtnBacklight(lp, LayoutParams.BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_OFF);
    else changeBtnBacklight(lp, LayoutParams.BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_NONE);
    win.setAttributes(lp);
}

private void changeBtnBacklight(LayoutParams lp, float value) {
    if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8) {
        try {
            new BtnBrightness(lp, value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Error changing button brightness");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static class BtnBrightness {
    BtnBrightness(LayoutParams lp, float v) {
        lp.buttonBrightness = v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to access `getWindow()` from outside an activity, like in a service?