# Turn off Button Backlight (like Nexus 1 soft buttons)

Tags: android

I know this is possible as the built in clock app and other apps are able to do it.

How do you turn off the button backlights from code?  These would be those like the softkeys on the bottom of the Nexus One screen.

Update:

Found this, but it only works on Froyo:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.buttonBrightness = 0;
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alex had an answer to this- although it is a hack. Since buttonBrightness was a private field before froyo, it uses reflection to access it.

[Turn off backlight of the buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966019/turn-off-buttons-backlight/4612700#4612700)

and this is how I use it in my project:

```
final Window win = getWindow();
final WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
winParams.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;

//set screen brightness to the lowest possible
winParams.screenBrightness = 0.01f;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
    // hack for pre-froyo to set buttonBrightness off
    try {
        Field buttonBrightness = winParams.getClass().getField(
                "buttonBrightness");
        buttonBrightness.set(winParams, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    winParams.buttonBrightness = 0;
}

win.setAttributes(winParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this section of the Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();
   //screen will stay on during this section...
wl.release();
```

By calling SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK you will set the screen to dim and the keyboard to off. Alternatively, you can call SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK which sets the screen to bright and the keyboard to off or PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK which turns both the screen and the keyboard off.

Comment: Tried that.  It only seems to turn off the keyboard backlight, not the softkey backlights.