# Alternate to use Window inside Android Services

Tags: android

i would like to use following code to turn off Button back that i got from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4937448/1218762

```
final Window win = getWindow();
final WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
winParams.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;

//set screen brightness to the lowest possible
winParams.screenBrightness = 0.01f;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
  // hack for pre-froyo to set buttonBrightness off
  try {
      Field buttonBrightness = winParams.getClass().getField(
            "buttonBrightness");
      buttonBrightness.set(winParams, 0);
     }   catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
} else {
 winParams.buttonBrightness = 0;
 }
win.setAttributes(winParams);
```

**Reference :** visit  [Night Mode](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pt.bbarao.nightmode&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInB0LmJiYXJhby5uaWdodG1vZGUiXQ) where you you can turn off Button Lights in Service , i know Services don't have Window but how is it possible ?

Thank You.

Comment: You want to turn of the Buttons backlight from a service?

Comment: yeah for reference you can see Night mode app from Play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the simple way I would suggest you is to broadcast some kind of *turning-off* message from your `Service` to your `Activity` and perform the required actions inside **onReceive** method of `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: buddy i want from Activity to Services cause above code is working fine in Activity

Comment: then simply do it in a reverse order **:)** or if you are good with services then perhaps do it with binding your service inside activity

Comment: i dont know how to do it , any link

Comment: read this: http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/android-development/broadcast-receiver-from-activity/

Comment: buddy i know broadcast receiver also service but dont know how to bind  services inside activity.

Comment: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/basics-of-android-part-iii-android-services/